# Hibernate 3.5.1, JPA2.0 & MySQL - Alternate behaviour within 2 diff dbs / same server

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, jpa-2.0

I am running a MySQL 5.1 server and Hibernate 3.5.1 / JPA2 for ORM. Everthing seems fine until I drop some tables manually. From then on, unit tests fail with Hibernate no longer creating certain tables. Changing the jdbc url from

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbjava?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

to

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbjavanew?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

solves the problem ... until I perform some table drops :-( Since I am going to use MySQL for production, this must not happen at all.

Dropping dbjava does not help too. Any suggestions?

--- ADDITIONAL INFO:

It's getting really weired. From mysql console:

```
mysql> use dbjava;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_dbjava    |
+---------------------+
| aa                  |
| ba                  |
| da                  |
| ea                  |
| hibernate_sequences |
| ia                  |
| ka                  |
| la                  |
+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> create table `cA` (id integer not null, comment varchar(255), name varchar(255), id_d integer, id_f integer, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'ca' already exists
```

Uh? Why does Table 'ca' exist?!?!? Actually, it once existed ... since then, it was dropped, the whole db was dropped several times ... why does it still exist?

Even worse:

```
 mysql> drop table cA;
 mysql> ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'ca'
```

Totally confused ...

**However, I just realised something: my table names in hibernate use lower and upper case (camel case) notation. mysql responses lower case only. Would anybody confirm that mysql does not recognize case-sensitiveness in the year 2010 ?!?**

Comment: You might want to run mysqlcheck against your database and/or check service logs for corruption(s).

Comment: Check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 1):

Which dialect are you using? Newer versions of Hibernate (can't remember exact numbers) have InnoDB dialect fix: instead of `type=InnoDb` it uses `engine=InnoDb` when creating tables -- which is the only legitimate syntax in MySQL 5.1. Just to remind, MySQL 5.0 accepted both `type` and `engine` keywords.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, however, it did not help. I added                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />  to appcontext.xml entity manager and           <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />   to persistence context. However, please mind the additional information I will give within 5 mins by editing my original question

Comment: If Hibernate could create the tables the first time, I don't see how the dialect could be guilty.